# Qt Installer Framework - Can't uninstall separate components

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I'm building a software (It's in French, for a french company, I didn't bother with the translations) and I'm packaging it with the Qt Installer Framework (Offline Installer). It's got 2 components, a "Core" component containing the executable and a second component containing base settings. I would like my user to be able to uninstall the software without uninstalling the "Settings" Component

[image: The software's components]

My problem is when runnning the maintenance tool, the "Add or Remove Components" is greyed out.

[image: The "Add or Remove Components" option greyed out]

Here's my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>Prigo Parcours</Name>
    <Version>0.3.0</Version>
    <Title>Prigo Parcours</Title>
    <Publisher>PrigoSoft</Publisher>
    <TargetDir>@HomeDir@/AppData/Local/PrigoParcours</TargetDir>
    <StartMenuDir>PrigoSoft</StartMenuDir>
    <InstallerWindowIcon>C:/Users/...</InstallerWindowIcon>
    <InstallerApplicationIcon>C:/Users/...</InstallerApplicationIcon>
    <Logo>C:/Users/...</Logo>
</Installer>
```

A here are both my components package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Package>
    <DisplayName>PrigoParcours</DisplayName>
    <Description>Le Composant principal de PrigoParcours</Description>
    <Version>0.3.0</Version>
    <ReleaseDate>2023-09-04</ReleaseDate>
    <Default>true</Default>
    <Name>be.prigosoft.parcours.core</Name>
    <Script>shortcuts.qs</Script>
</Package>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Package>
    <DisplayName>PrigoParcours - Réglages</DisplayName>
    <Description>Les réglages PrigoParcours</Description>
    <Version>0.3.0</Version>
    <ReleaseDate>2023-09-04</ReleaseDate>
    <Default>true</Default>
    <Name>be.prigosoft.parcours.settings</Name>
</Package>
```

I've looked in the Qt docs, didn't find anything.